# Time(only & not date) comparison

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

I need to compare two different times. Both of the format:

> Hour:Min:Sec

None of them is picked up from **current time**. So, no `strtotime` or `DateTime`. I don't want the date to be involved in any way in the comparison.
Every question here ends with `strtotime` as the answer.

What I want is to compare these two times out of which one is getting picked from DataBase(is of the type `time`) & one I'm manually giving as string.

For eg: `$A="00:00:00"`(if can be stored otherwise kindly do tell).

If there is any way to do this,kindly do tell me?Thnxx in advance...

Comment: you can use one date to compare times within this date

Comment: Like i said one time i'm giving manually. Although not a good practice but that time is going to be hardcoded & I need to compare it with the time in DB that may vary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If time is in 24 hour format you can simply compare it by string comparison

```
$A="00:00:00"
$B="13:00:00"

if ($A > $B) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: the data I'm receiving from the database is of the type 'time'
so can't really compare

Comment: I believe when php reads from your database, the 'time' type will be converted to string automatically. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a function that convert your times into seconds and then do a comparison based on the results

```
function getTimeInSeconds($hours, $minutes, $seconds) {
    $totalSeconds = 0;

    //Add the numner of  hours in seconds
    $totalSeconds += ($hours * 60) * 60;

    //Add the number of minutes in seconds
    $totalSeconds += $minutes * 60;

    //Add seconds
    $totalSeconds += $seconds;

    return $totalSeconds;
}

$firsttime = getTimeInSeconds(8, 30, 14);
$secondtime = getTimeInSeconds(10, 15, 06);

//If second time is later than first time
if($secondtime > $firsttime)
{
}

//If first time is later than second time
if($firsttime > $secondtime)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use `strtotime` or `DateTime` i'm not sure it will gives you correct output cause it will be compare as a string or int values so not possible to calculate exact time so better to use php date and time functions

```
For eg: $A="00:00:00" (it will be a string value)
```

so better output will be convert both values using `strtotime()` and do your stuff

Comment: sorry...can't use that. it would be kind of my last resort & would include string splicing

Answer (score 0):

You could just multiply out the seconds and compare them.

```
$timebits = explode(':',$A);
$secondsDB = $timebits[2] + timebits[1]*60 + $timebits[0]*60*60
```

and then compare to your manual time in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If you require to compare if times on format HH:MM:SS are equal or if one is before another and don't want to use strtotime function you should convert all to seconds and compare as numbers.

Simple example:

```
$a="01:30:08";
$b="02:20:50";

function toseconds($str){
  $array = explode(":",$str);
  $val  = $array[0] * 24 * 60;
  $val += $array[1] * 60;
  $val += $array[2];
  return $val;
}

print toseconds($a); // print a
print " compare to ";
print toseconds($b); // print b
print " ";

if($a > $b){
    print "b is before a";
}else if ($b > $a){
    print "a is before b";
}else if($b == $a){
    print "a and b are the same time";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CAST( )](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) function in mysql query

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE yourcolumn < CAST('05:00:00' AS time)
```

Comment: just 1 question for you. why did you downvote all my questions?

Comment: @shaktimaan If i were,why i answer you again ?

Comment: ok sure whatever buddy...just remember SO is not for this kinda stuff.
& as for your answer,i already discussed it with k102 in comments just below the question